# datetime struggle with a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am running the following **code**:

```
filled_df = (ts.set_index(date_col)
                 .groupby(grouping)
                 .apply(lambda d: d.reindex(
                     pd.date_range(
                         mf_heuristic(d.index, champion_end), pd.to_datetime(
                             dt.datetime.now()
                         ),
                         freq='MS')
                 )
    )
        .drop(grouping, axis=1)
        .reset_index(grouping)
        .fillna(0)
```

*with the predefinitions:*

```
date_col = 'timepoint'
grouping = ['Level', 'Kontogruppe']
champion_end = fc_date - pd.DateOffset(months=13)

print(champion_end)
2021-03-01 00:00:00

print(ts)
Kontogruppe  Level   timepoint    data_value
0       A   ZBFO  2020-03-01      1
1       B   ZBFO  2020-07-01      1612.59
2       A   ZBFO  2020-08-01      1046.1

print(ts.dtypes)
Kontogruppe     object
Level           object
timepoint       object
data_value         float64
dtype: object
```

```
def mf_heuristic(date, champion_end):
        
        if min(date) < champion_end:
            start_date = min(date)
        else:
            
            start_date = min(date)
        return start_date
```

When I run the code, I get the following **error massage**:

> TypeError: Cannot compare Timestamp with datetime.date. Use ts ==
> pd.Timestamp(date) or ts.date() == date instead.

for the line with the mf_heuristic function.

If I try to put before:

```
ts[date_col] = pd.Timestamp(ts[date_col])
```

I get the error massage:

> TypeError: function missing required argument 'year' (pos 1)

Comment: Does it really matter? the `champion_end` is important

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `to_datetime`:

```
ts[date_col] = pd.to_datetime(ts[date_col])
```

Comment: That works out, whats the reason? And why the error provided a different solution?

Comment: `pd.Timestamp` requires you to supply year, month and day as numbers, not a string. For example, `pd.Timestamp(2023,7,27)`. The other error in your code was self explanatory. You can't compare a Timestamp with a date. So you need to convert the timestamp to date or the date to timestamp. I chose the latter.